# How to increase the speed of sprite in cocos2D xcode?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on cocos2D.I used CCSpeed  for increasing the speed of the sprite but it's not working.How to change the speed of sprite dynamically?Can anyone provide me some information regarding this.

Comment: provide more information and possible code

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to do. CCSpeed is something like "cover" over other actions. You can change speed of moving, rotating, scaling, etc. If you want to move some node (sprite in your case), use CCMoveTo or CCMoveBy action.

Comment: Ya I didlike this  id move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(10,0)];
        id action = [CCSpeed actionWithAction: move speed:5.0f];[spritename runaction:action];but the speed of sprite is same it's not increasing.